# Json property undefined after using .Json()

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

**JSON RESPONSE AFTER .JSON Is Called**

registerResponse is an API call for clarifaction

```
{
"person": {
    "name": "jeff",
    "state": "Florida",
    "city": "miami"
  },
  "food": "tacos",
  "drink": "water"
}
```

```
let response = registerResponse()
console.log(response.json().food)
console.log(response.json().person.state)
```

the first log input works but the second input throws an error.
"cannot read property 'state' of undefined"
is there a reason this is happening am i doing it wrong? I can remove state but then it just returns null. I'm suspecting the .json() method is not good with nested objects

Comment: Show `registerResponse`

Comment: it returns the json above.

Comment: If it return json, why do you call `json()` on the json?

Comment: [`json`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Response/json) is an asynchronous method. Please read the docs which contain correct examples of its usage.

Answer (score -1):

What is the `registerResponse` function? Assuming it is similar to `fetch`, calling `.json()` consumes the response body which means you can only call it once. You would need to save it to a variable:

```
const data = response.json()

console.log(data.food)
console.log(data.person.state)
```

Comment: yes its a fetch, unfortunately i get the same error :(